# Error on expo XDE While opening it on Windows 10

Tags: react-native, expo

I just installed the `expo Desktop xde` on `windows 10` when I open the app I get this error:

> Error parsing JSON file: C:\Users\username.expo\state.json └─ Cause: SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0

[image: parsing error]

Do you have any idea why is that ?

Comment: Have you looked in the file specified in the error message? Have you done any effort yourself?

Comment: I have actually and this is what's on the json file:
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

Comment: You should put that in the question, rather than a comment.

Comment: Right, thanks that's duly noted

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I had to delete all the Expo files on my pc and reinstall it again and it worked.